How can I determine the number of harmonics for this case?
I would like to comment here on a question I have regarding an analysis of an experiment I must present and I thought I could find some answers here to certain problems I'm having.
In short, I am trying to verify how temperature affects the speed at which a sound wave propagates in a resonance tube open at both ends.
I have the shapes of several waves at different temperatures (9°C, 26°C, 40°C and 90°C), I have analyzed them in Raven Lite, and with an estimate I can calculate the period, to then obtain the frequency.
The dilemma is when calculating the wavelength. When using the equation that relates the length of the tube (if it is open), the number of harmonics $n$ and the frequency.
I used the fundamental $n=1$ in my calculations, I read that it makes the calculations less tedious and that there may be more harmonics in the tube but the first one can be used. So I did my calculations for each frequency (1kHz, 2kHz, etc.) and I had concluded that the calculations were correct until today's class.
The first thing the professor pointed out to me is that they are not reasonable, since the fundamental harmonic is at a much lower frequency (approx. 200Hz), and that the subsequent calculations were not correct since it should be a higher harmonic due to the much higher frequency. Also something related to the fact that the wavelength should not be 2L since that would only be up to the middle of the tube (I did not quite understand what he meant by this).
He mentioned to me that the material should not influence it so much while it travels in the material since it is not transmitted through the material, and that there should not be much difference between a PVC tube and a metal one.
My question is, how can I solve the calculations? What number of harmonics should I use in each case? How can I know what number of harmonics should be used for each frequency? Is there an equation? Or is there something I am not understanding well?
We did not have much time for this and tomorrow we have to present the corrected results.
Any information would be greatly appreciated.
I apologize for anything that is not well understood, English is not my first language
